# Why was Robert Patrick never recruited again after Terminator 2?

Tags: casting, terminator-series

Why was Robert Patrick never recruited again after Terminator 2?

Why wasn't he recruited in Genisys?

Comment: ...his physique has altered from the T-1000's over the years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems he didn't want to unless it was with James Cameron...

> In the past, Robert Patrick has been everything from against, to luke-warm towards, reprising the iconic role that made him famous. But now things have changed. This is apparently due to the return of James Cameron to the Terminator franchise.
>
> This is what Robert Patrick had to say about it to Yahoo, in regards to playing the T-1000 again:
>
> > ROBERT PATRICK: “I would. I thought about this. I’ve been sort of… it’s changed my position over the years but yes, I would, I certainly would. Especially now that Jim Cameron has the franchise back in his hands. The common denominator I think between Terminator and Terminator 2 is the fact that **Jim Cameron directed both of those films. If he’s involved, I would love to be involved again.**  I honestly can’t say I can do it quite as well as I did it as a 30 year old physically, but I sure would give it my best effort.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://skynetsarmy.wordpress.com/2017/06/14/t-1000-actor-robert-patrick-discusses-a-return-to-the-terminator-franchise/)</sup>

James Cameron will acquire the rights back in 2019, as copyright reversion takes place after 35 years. More at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(franchise)#Terminator_Genisys_.282015.29)

Comment: Of course they'd have to explain why Skynet bothers to make its terminators appear to age... extreme long term deep cover assignments maybe!

Comment: Maybe they've figured out that old people are less threatening and therefore more likely to succeed at infiltration.

Comment: That made me chuckle @Steve-O  LOL